# How to use google map tiles/layers (hybrid,satellite) with in Osm in Android?

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap

I am using open street map api in my android app. I did not find  equivalent of google satellite view in osm. How to use google satellite or hybrid view in osm ?

Comment: Your question is too broad. What prevents you from using the google aerial tiles?

Comment: I need google satellite  tile url for osm . I didn't find it

Comment: "google satellite tile url for osm" doesn't make any sense. You need the google satellite tile URL which has nothing to do with OSM at all.

Comment: Ok I got it. You say any satellite tile url is usable for osm .

Comment: Yes. But there is no "for osm". OSM is a database. You must be referring to a specific tool or library you are using, for example osmdroid.